# Question about repository pattern

Tags: .net, repository-pattern

Is this a good or bad idea?

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    ...
    IList<T> Get(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    ...
}
```

I mean - it seems really powerful addition and i could implement it too (at least - to some level) but my guts tells me it's kind a wrong. Could anyone enlighten me?

Comment: @AdamRalph If i knew - i wouldn't ask. That's just an intuition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it certainly is a powerful feature. The problem is: introducing it in the interface will force all implementations of `IRepository` to provide a suitable definition -- which might not be possible (or at least really hard) depending on the implementation (say, an implementation backed by a database connection or something).

Maybe, you should instead do

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    ...
}

public interface IAdvancedRepository<T>: IRepository<T> 
{
    IList<T> Get(Func<T, bool> predicate)
}
```

and provide `Get` only, if the implementation can do it efficiently.

Comment: Thought about this too. But i wanted to know - is that's a good idea to provide this kind of API (querying by hyper generic predicate) in general. That leads to abscence of necessity of repository methods like 'FindByCountryName' and 'GetByLastName'. Basically - i'm moving outside from repositories an answer to question what exactly i'm querying. It just seems that i'm missing something and this can lead to serious problems in future.

Comment: The problem is, that you are effectively forcing a "full table scan" with this solution, that is, even if your repository implementation had an index on (say) LastName (a hash table, a DB index, etc.), you could not use this in the implementation of Get, as you don't know, which properties get actually tested by the predicate. This imposes severe constraints on the implementation of `IRespository`.

Comment: You shouldn't delete that point about indexes. I think that's a valid point. Lack of explicitness can lead to harder maintenance of database.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is better :

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
IQueryable<T> GetAll();
}
```

then you can write your custom queries as :

```
var employees=Repositroy<Employee>.GetAll().Where(emp=>emp.Salary>10000).Select(emp=>emp).ToList();
```

Comment: It is if we know that exposing full querying API ain't bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to link 'Get' with getting one simple instance, not a list.
Therefore, when I have a method which returns a collection, I usually name that method 'Find' or something like that.

(Note that FxCop will tell you it is a bad idea to use 'Get' as a function name).

Ah, Ok, I missed the point. :)
I would not create a method which takes a a criteria as an argument.  I'd rather have specialized methods on my repository instead of passing in all sorts of criteria.
I know, it is not as flexible, but it is just more explicit.

Comment: That's already closer to point. But is it just about explicitness?

Answer (score 0):

For me it smells like you don't really need a repository as .NET devs usually understand it.

I think you need something like this:

```
public interface IStore {
    // Low-level abstraction over a real database
}

public interface IAction<TInput, TResult> { // Or maybe ICommand?
    TResult Execute(TInput input);
}

// then:
public interface IGetCustomerById : IAction<int, Customer> {
}
public class GetCustomerById : IGetCustomerById {
    IStore store;
    public GetCustomerById(IStore store) {
        this.store = store;
    }

    public Customer Execute(int id) {
        return store.ResultOfExecutedSqlOrWhatever(id);
    }
}
// it might not only be READ action but more complex one, reusing other actions too
public class ApproveCustomer<ApprovalInfo,ApprovalResult> : IAction {
    IStore store;
    IGetCustomerById getCustomer;
    public ApproveCustomer(IStore store, IGetCustomerById getCustomer) {
        this.store = store;
        this.getCustomer = getCustomer;
    }

    public ApprovalResult Execute(ApprovalInfo approval) {
        var customer = getCustomer.Execute(approval.CustomerId);
        var result = new ApprovalResult();
        if (customer == null) {
            result.Message = "No such customer";
            return result;
        }
        if (!customer.IsEligibleForSomething()) { // This can be another action!
            result.Message = "Not eligible"
            return result;
        }
        result.Message = "Successfully approved"
        result.IsApproved = true;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Additional benefit here is that all these actions can be easily used with dependency injection.